# Digamma function and asymptotic bounds

Tags: asymptotics, wolfram-alpha, digamma-function

Knowing that $m\to \infty$, $n\to \infty$, $m^2<n^{2/3}$, I came across the following expression:
$$\frac{2x^2}{\frac{x^2m^2}{n^{2/3}}+m^4n^{2/3}}$$
Playing a bit with said expression, I saw it increases until $x=mn^{2/3}$ and then decreases once again, all the while being $o(1)$ in one form or another.

I was wondering if summing it from $x=1$ to $x=n$ will be $o(1)$ (and if not, how far can I sum it so it will still be $o(1)$). I tried to see what WolframAlpha was suggesting, and it led to this:

[WolframAlpha Suggestion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20x%3D1%20to%20n%20of%20%5B2x%2F((x%5E2*%20m%5E2)%2Fn%5E(2%2F3)%20%2B(m%5E4%20n%5E(2%2F3)))%5D)

An expression involving the Digamma function, which I never came across. I was wondering if anyone has a suggestion as to the original question, or how to deal with what WolframAlpha suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I do not know if this is better.*

You can use generalized harmonic numbers and get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2 x}{m^4 n^{2/3}+\frac{m^2 x^2}{n^{2/3}}}=\frac{n^{2/3}} {m^2}\left(H_{n-i m n^{2/3}}+H_{n+i
   n^{2/3} m}-H_{-i m n^{2/3}}-H_{i m n^{2/3}}\right)$$

Comment: Well it is certainly better. But coming to think about it, my roots are real roots - so why would the $i$ even pop to matter?

Comment: @Studentmath. If you use the asymptotics of the harmonic numbers, the result would be real. I just made it for $m=1$ and it is fine. The complex part comes from the partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Thank you. Just to see we are on the same page, it seems it no longer maintains its $o(1)$ property, when $m=o(n^{1/3})$?